# C scanf not working in recursive function

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to write a function which takes and checks if the input is an integer between 1 and 1000. If not, it calls itself. However, If I give a wrong input, for example, "F" , it doesn't stop for the scanf, rather becomes an infinite loop. Any suggestion?
Is it something to do with the input buffer?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int num,input;


int take_input()
{ 
  num =  scanf("%d", &input);

  if( num != 1 || input < 1 || input > 1000 )
  {
    printf("input must be between 1 and 1000");
    take_input();
  }
  return 1;
}

int main()
{  
  take_input();
}
```

Comment: When `scanf()` fails to read the requested type, it leaves the input in the buffer, so the next call reads the same thing, gets the same error, and so on and so on.

Comment: There are hundreds of questions here about scanf. Did you try searching for similar problems before posting your question?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but using recursion here is pure nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

First: you don't need to check if (num != 1) in the second test... it will only get there if the first test was false.

Second: you are passing only one argument to be read: scanf will return either 1 or 0 (if it didnt read correctly). So what happens is: if you read one number then **num** will have value 1 and you will exit right after it in the first if.

To make your recursion work you have to:

```
 if(num != 1 )
    return 1;
 if( input < 1 || num > 1000 ) 
 {
    printf("input must be between 1 and 1000");
    take_input();
 }
```

This way it will keep asking for a new value while the current value is not in specified interval.

Comment: 1) I would expect `scanf("%d", ...)` to return 1 of 3 results: 0, 1 or EOF. 2) This solution could infinitely recurse if `EOF` was encountered.

Comment: is EOF != 1? yes, return 1; where is the infinite loop? @chux

Comment: 1) I stand  corrected - no infinite recursion.  2) Suspect test should be `if(input < 1 || input > 1000 )`

Comment: suspect is the use of this function.... he reads in a variable and regardless of what he read, he always returns 1, ane never uses the variable for anything... the test however, is gonna call the function again when the value read is not in the range [1, 1000]... but there is no need to use recursion for this, a simple while loop can take care of that

Answer (score 0):

take_input if statements should check against input variable and not num.
When you do scanf you store the result of what you read in &input. Replace
num with input.